# How to use PercenRelativeLayout for listView item

Tags: android, listview, android-percentrelativelayout

I'm trying to use **PercenRelativeLayout** into **ListView,** but it doesnot works,
height and width percents are ignored and nothing were showing into the listview.
it works only for **marshmallows**.

here is list item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:background="#d20404"
    android:id="@+id/test_image_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />

<TextView
    android:background="#000"
    android:text="sfgfashdsfg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test_image_id"
    app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

I have a sample project on [github](https://github.com/developer--/PercentRelativeLayoutDemo)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. This would include the layout where you are using `PercentRelativeLayout` and the code where you employ that layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened this issue to google. **The answer were**

> The height of your ListView row item is insufficiently specified.
>
> The first child says it wants to take 60% of the row height (note that
>   this is heightPercent and not aspectRatio), and the second child says
>   it wants to take 10% of the row height. But nothing tells ListView how
>   tall the entire row wants to be. So it ends up being with height 0.
>
> Note that the semantics of height=match_parent do not work in ListView
>   rows, and if this works in any one particular Android platform version
>   (for however much you can say it works), it is purely incidental.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202479

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with android K and android L.

> The percent layout won't work correctly before android M. The reason is that they depend on the size hint being delivered in the measuring step. Before android M most layouts would provide size hint 0.

***Convert your percent relative layout to relative layout and set the height of the views programmatically according to your device height.***

This is not a very elegant solution but it worked for me.

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_image_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#d20404" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/test_image_id"
    android:background="#000"
    android:text="sfgfashdsfg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code:**

```
// to get the height of the screen
int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

// to set height to each textview to 50% of screen
textView1.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height * 0.50);
```